# React js Lifecycle question: Why the same component is rendered twice?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

Please refer to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lifecycle-test-1-w9upx

My question is, in the console log:

```
AuthWrapper: rendering... 
AuthWrapper: rendering... 
UserNavBar: rendering... 
UserNavBar: rendering... 
AuthWrapper: authenticated 
AuthWrapper: rendering... 
AuthWrapper: rendering... 
UserNavBar: rendering... 
UserNavBar: rendering... 
UserNavBar: fetching user data...
```

Why do components render twice? Thanks.

Comment: This could be because of using React strict mode

Comment: It's because of strict mode. Don't disable strict mode though, because: 1) this only happens in development, not in the production build. 2) this is used to manifest right away a whole class of bugs.

Comment: 3) your code is supposed to run the same if the components have one or more useless rerenders. This should only cause a minor performance impact and nothing else.